# Gmap not loading when zooming

Tags: google-maps

I have a weired issue and no idea how to address it. I use a block view on my front page that displays a gmap. When the page loads the map is displayed correctely. When I zoom in or out the map doesn't load (sometimes it loads one or two levels, sometimes no level). The weired thing is, when I use the exposed filter for that view and the gmap loads again (using Ajax), the zooming works just fine. So it seems that when the map is getting loaded again it works but not if the page gets refreshed.

The site I'm talking about is [www.my-business-location.com](http://www.my-business-location.com/).

BTW: Other gmaps that I use with the gmap field module work well.

Does somebody have an idea what causes this behaviour or how I could find the mistake?

Comment: In the error console, I see: "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."

Comment: Please add some more information to the question, steps for someone else to reproduce the problem in a fresh install of Drupal would be ideal. A link to your site isn't useful, because as soon as you fix the problem the question becomes impossible for future users to comprehend